# What's the explicit relationship between the PGF of the minimum of N i.i.d random variables and the PGF of that random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables

$X_i$ for $i\in\{ 1,2,\ldots,n\}$  are i.i.d positive integer random variable, of which
the probability generating function  is given by $G_{X_i}(z) =\sum^{+\infty}_{k=1}\text{Pr}\{X_i=k \} z^{k}$.

Let $Y= \min \{ X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n\}.$ Then, my question is: how to derive the probability generating function  of $Y$, $G_{Y}(z)$, given $G_{X_i}(z)$. In specific,  what's the explicit relationship between $G_{Y}(z)$ and $G_{X_i}(z)$?

I would highly appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$Pr(Y=k)=\prod\limits_{m=1}^nPr(X_m\ge k)-\prod\limits_{m=1}^nPr(X_m\ge k+1)$

Getting the generating function?

Comment: It does not look promising.$$G_Y(z)~{ = \sum_{k=1}^\infty z^k\Pr(Y=k)\\=\sum_{k=1}^\infty z^k(\prod_{j=1}^n\Pr(X\geq k)-\prod_{j=1}^n\Pr(X\geq k+1))\\=\sum_{k=1}^\infty z^k(\Pr(X\geq k)^n-\Pr(X\geq k+1)^n)\\=\sum_{k=1}^\infty z^k\left(\left(\sum_{j=k}^\infty\Pr(X=j)\right)^n-\left(\sum_{j=k+1}^\infty\Pr(X=j)\right)^n\right)\\\vdots}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $p_i=P(X_1=i).$ We have $$\begin{align}P(Y>k)&=\left(P(X_1>k)\right)^n\\&=\left(1-P(X_1\leq k)\right)^n\\
&=\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^kp_i\right)^n
\end{align}$$

Then $$\begin{align}P(Y=k)&=P(Y>k-1)-P(Y>k)\\
&=\left(1-\sum_1^{k-1}p_i\right)^n-\left(1-\sum_1^k p_i\right)^n
\end{align}$$

I don’t think you can you can express $G_Y$ in terms of $G_X.$